# What Dominion kingdom-card setups tend to lead to the shortest games?

Tags: dominion, play-time

Most dominion players notice early on that different kingdom sets have GIGANTIC effects on how the game ends up being played. This also means that some games will end fairly quickly, while others will go on longer.

What Dominion kingdom-card setups tend to lead to the **shortest** games when all players are trying to win? What kingdom-cards specifically tend to contribute most to making games end sooner? Feel free to give specific setups if you like, but I'm also interested in what cards/combos make for shorter games and why/how they do this. For instance, some cards sets encourage players to try for an early lead and then end the game on piles before their opponents can catch up, while some card sets tend to favor strategies where players build up an extremely powerful deck until they get to a turn where they churn out 20+ victory points. What cards cause dominion games at the shorter end of the spectrum to be that way?

Related: [What Dominion kingdom-card setups tend to lead to the LONGEST games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6943/what-dominion-kingdom-card-setups-tend-to-lead-to-the-longest-games)

Comment: Could you clarify the problem you are trying to solve here?  As stated, this looks like a request for discussion.  Do you find Dominion games taking too long?

Comment: Pat does a good job continuing to make sure there is nothing interesting to read (or write) bcg.se.  FWIW, forum.dominionstrategy.com will give you good, high quality discussion of this if you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Kingdom setups with +Buy, gain free cards, tend to end on piles instead of Provinces.

- Workshop, Garden
- Ironworks, Great Hall
- Goons
- Smugglers
- Werehouse, Treasure Map

Comment: Particularly if the cheapest cards are useful non-terminals like Hamlet, Haven, etc.  If 3 piles are cards that you can ALWAYS want more of without hurting your deck, they'll go fast.